# How can I convert string representation of a dictionary to a dictionary? json.loads() showing JSONDecodeError: Expecting a ',' delimeter

Tags: python-3.x

```
with open('encdb.csv') as MC, open('encgadb.csv') as S:
for x, y in zip(MC, S):
    print(type(x))
    res = json.loads(x)
    print(type(res))
```

I am trying to read from csv file

Comment: Can you add the first few lines of your .csv file? You get that error when the string passed to `json.loads` is not properly formatted JSON

Comment: Also, your `for` block should be indented inside the `with` block

Comment: It is working now. It was showing error because of csv file. I've converted csv file to text format it is working now.